# "Not Implemented" error when testing a Scalatra route with ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalatra

I am writing tests for several Scalatra routes.  I'm using Scala 2.10.2, Scalatra 2.2.1, and Scalatest 1.9.2; I'm fairly new at using all three of these.  I'm also using Eclipse Scala IDE 3.0.1 with the ScalaTest plugin.

For my ScalatraBootstrap I have

```
context.mount(new AccountsController, "/accounts")
context.mount(new ProfilesController, "/profiles")
```

Inside ProfilesController I have the following route

```
val addImage =
  (apiOperation[Int]("addImage")
    parameters (pathParam[String]("context").description("Profile context"),
    pathParam[Int]("id").description("Profile Id"),
    Parameter("body", "body data",
      DataType[ScalatraRecord],
      paramType = ParamType.Body)))
post("/:context/:id/images", operation(addImage)) { ... }
```

This is tested with

```
test("add a profile image") {
  val json = JObject("name" -> JString("asdf")) merge JObject("image_file_url" -> JString("test.png"))
  val bytes = compact(render(json)).getBytes("utf-8")
  post("/profiles/users/1/images", bytes, Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")) {
    status should be(200)
  }
}
```

This passees the test.

Inside AccountsController I have the following route

```
val addContact =
  (apiOperation[Int]("addContact")
  parameters (
    Parameter("contact", "new contact data",
      DataType[Contact],
      paramType = ParamType.Body)))
post("/contacts", operation(addContact)) { ... }
```

Tested with

```
test("add contact") {
  val json = JObject("name" -> JString(rand.nextString(10))) merge JObject("email" -> JString(rand.nextString(10)))
  val bytes = compact(render(json)).getBytes("utf-8")
  post("/accounts/contacts", bytes, Map("Content-Type" -> "application/json")) {
    status should be(200)
  }
}
```

This fails; the status is 500, and the body is "Not Implemented."  The route works fine in production.  I tested a `get("/accounts/contacts")` route to make sure that I didn't have any typos, and this route also works fine.  As far as I can tell, the only difference between the two routes is that the profile route has two path params and uses a different data type for its body param (the test that succeeds uses ScalatraRecord, the test that fails uses Contact; Contact inherits from ScalatraRecord); I tried adding bogus path params to the account route and I also tried changing the type of its body param to match the profile's param, but I ran into the same error.

I don't understand why one route would pass the test while the other route would give me a "Not Implemented" error.  Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can fix this?